# How my function can take all arguments of another fucntion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to create a class that deals with OpenCV images.

For that, I was thinking of passing to class already an image.

```
img = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

class myClass():
   def __init__(self, frame):
      self.frame = frame

inst = myClass(img)
```

But I want to pass my class only the path to the image. How can I do that my class can be able to take all the arguments taht cv2.imread takes?

Something like

```
inst = myClass(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Comment: Sure...just take the arguments and then make `img` in the `__init__`.  Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, path, flags):
        self.frame = cv2.imread(path, flags)

inst = MyClass(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Answering question asked below:

Note that that documentation for `cv2.imread()` says that it takes exactly two arguments, so that's precisely what I provided for.  For a more general case:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.frame = some_builder(*args, **kwargs)
```

would cause `some_builder` to be called with precisely the arguments (non-keyword and keyword) that the `__init__` method was called with.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! What if there are more than one flag?

Comment: Added more info.